# Probability of Three Heads if First Toss is a Head

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm working through Grimaldi's textbook on Discrete Mathematics, and for Exercise 6 in Section 3.6, the provided answer doesn't make sense to me.  I'm almost positive the book is wrong, but I thought I'd share just in case I'm missing something.

Here is the question.  Say you toss a fair coin 5 times.  What is the probability you get three heads if the first toss is a head?

(For reference, the book gives the answer as $\frac{3}{4}$.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is that the exact wording of the question? Your solution seems right to me but I want to be sure that there's not some subtlety of the question that's getting lost.

Comment: Sure, here's the question verbatim: "Celia tosses a fair coin five times.  What is the probability she gets three heads, if the first toss results in (a) a head;..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I approached it. The number of outcomes in the sample space is $ | \mathscr{S} | = 2^5 = 32$.  Let $A$ be the number of times you get 3 heads, and $B$ be the number times the first toss is a head.  Therefore, $|A| = \binom{5}{3} = 10$ and $ |B| = 2^4 = 16$.  That means $Pr(A) = \frac{10}{32} = 0.3125$ and $Pr(B) = \frac{16}{32} = 0.5$.

For the set $A \cap B$, we have $| A \cap B| = \binom{4}{2} = 6 $, because if the first flip is heads, we only need to find the number of ways to choose two heads out of the remaining four flips.  Thus, $Pr(A \cap B) = \frac{6}{32} = 0.1875$.

Since the goal is to find $P(A|B)$, we use Bayes' theorem here (i.e., $ Pr(A|B) = \frac{Pr(A \cap B)}{Pr(B)}$).  Therefore,

$$ Pr(A|B) = \frac{Pr(A \cap B)}{Pr(B)} = \frac{0.1875}{0.5} =  0.375 $$

Comment: Seems good to me (i.e. I agree that the book contains a mistake). My only comment on your solution: you're working much harder than you need to. You hit the crux here: "...if the first flip is heads, we only need to find the number of ways to choose two heads out of the remaining four flips..." Hence, the answer is the 6 you found out of $2^4$ (the size of a 4-coin sample space), or $6/16$.

Comment: Ah, I guess you're right.  Thank you!